# How can I compare two huge matrix and find similar rows element by element in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have two csv files, called file1 and file2. File1 contains 5k rows of 29 elements each, and File2 has 6k rows of 31 elements each. I need to search every row in File1 and find it in file2, and if it doesn't exist find the row with more matches. I tried iterating over each row of both matrices and comparing element by element, but it's extremely inefficient and takes ages. Is there any better way of making this comparation?

Im working with python 3

Comment: Please post your attempts so far.  What does your code look like?

Comment: Consider using a Trie to do the `search`.